# iPhone Mail displays the wrong number of drafts

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

I recently cleaned up my email drafts folder.  I had 62 messages, and now I have only 6 email drafts saved.

[image: GMail Drafts]

My iPhone, however, still shows a count of 62! Only the 6 that really exist are available, but the count is still off.

[image: iPhone Drafts]

How can I force the phone to re-count the number of drafts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the iPhone to create a new, 7th junk Draft.  That action corrected the count.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the Drafts folder; that will start synchronizing the folder with what's in your Gmail folder.

I've noticed this happening for some of the Gmail folders on iPhone. As long as you don't access them, they don't all update.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be a synchronization setting. But the phone is and has been set correctly to store drafts on the server, and not on the phone.

[image]